# Segmentation fault (Core dumped) after updating to lollipop 5.1

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-emulator, ubuntu-12.04

I've recently got the latest android sdk lollipop 5.1 through sdkManager.

After creating a Emulator with Lollipop 5.1, it doesn't even loading the home screen. Tried as many times. After flashing android screen for some minutes, it just closes itself. What would be the problem?

By launching from Terminal with debug mode, i get the error :

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

So, searched `stackoverflow` and found this :

```
mv tools/lib/libOpenglRender.so tools/lib/libOpenglRender.so.xxx
```

It doesn't work too. It throws error like

> emulator: ERROR: Could not load OpenGLES emulation library: libOpenglRender.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>   emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
>   Segmentation fault (core dumped)